# Coxeter groups - Suzuki group theory I

Tags: group-theory, coxeter-groups

At the start of the section Coxeter groups in Suzuki's *"Group theory I"*, we have Coxeter group W with generating set $S$. we have $T$ as the set of elements of $W$ that are conjugate to some element of $S$. It says for a sequence $\mathfrak{s}=(s_1,…,s_q) $ with $s_i \in S$ we define $\mathfrak{t} = (t_1,…,t_q) $ where $$t_i = (s_1…s_{i-1})s_i (s_1…s_{i-1})^{-1}.$$

Using this, what is $t_1 $ defined to be? I take it we just have $t_1=s_1$?

Comment: Yes, $t_1$ is equal to $s_1$, which is exactly what Suzuki's formula gives. The empty product is the identity.